# Bevel modifier buckling bug

Tags: modifiers, edges, bevel

I've noticed on the bevel modifier that **edges at vertex junctions of three or more bevels actually buckle in and out when using a profile of 1.** I want these to be straight and not bow out/in since I'm using these meshes for NURBS conversion and having something imprecise like this can be quite a problem for production. I want a 1 profile since it holds edges like controlling loops normally would and decreases the time it would take to cut all loops by hand.

Here's a screenshot of it buckling compared to a .99 profile (even with .99 profile it pinches too (outside edgeloops) which isn't desirable. If there is a fix or a plugin for this let me know!

[image: Bevel issue]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Bad news

This is a bug in Blender 2.79b. It has already been reported.

### Good news

There has already been a fix for this. If you download **Master** at https://builder.blender.org/download/ and check with the exact same file, the Bevel should work as expected. The same fix has also been applied to the 2.80 series of Blender as well.

Comment: Thanks! I was downloading Blender 2.8 to see if there was a fix while waiting on an answer.